# Selenium webdriver not running continuously as aspected

Tags: java, eclipse, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I am running selenium webdriver to insert some records in my website but it got stuck after 3 - 4 records and give error "org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element" while those tags are present.
I have tried Wait, implicit timeout but again getting same error.
Language - Java,
OS - Window 7 64 bit,
Browser - IE8,
IDE - Eclips

Most of the time given snippet and locator create problem.

I am posting HTML snippet and locator :-

1) HTML:-

```
<SELECT class=textbox150 tabIndex=10 onchange=onChgVal(this) name=dd_acct_fed_wthld_ind origValue="4" groupID="dpacct" req="yes" type="text">
<OPTION value=0>0 - Exempt, assumed</OPTION>
<OPTION value=1>1 - Exempt, foreign</OPTION>
<OPTION value=2>2 - Exempt, corporation</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

Fecting value by name 'dd_acct_fed_wthld_ind'

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name(“dd_acct_fed_wthld_ind”)));

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name(“dd_acct_fed_wthld_ind”)));   

WebElement option = select.getFirstSelectedOption();
String str = option.getText(); 
driver.findElement(By.name("dd_acct_fed_wthld_ind")).sendKeys("1 - Exempt, foreign");
```

2.)HTML:-

```
<TEXTAREA style="OVERFLOW: hidden" onkeydown="return checkMaxLength(this,event,300)" id=ci_rmrk_lne1_txt tabIndex=30 onkeyup="return checkEnter(event)" rows=5 onchange=onChgVal(this) cols=70 name=ci_rmrk_lne1_txt origValue="Test" groupID="cicust" req="yes">Testing</TEXTAREA>
```

Fecting value by name 'ci_rmrk_lne1_txt'

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.Id(“ci_rmrk_lne1_txt”)));

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.Id(“ci_rmrk_lne1_txt”)));  

WebElement option = select.getFirstSelectedOption();
String str = option.getText(); 
driver.findElement(By.id("ci_rmrk_lne1_txt")).sendKeys("Hi");
```

Comment: Causes for that error:  A bad selector, you aren't waiting long enough for the element to appear (it may be loaded by javascript), or it is in an i-frame.

Comment: @MrTi I am waiting for 60 second and I can see that field on page(open by selenium webdriver). May you please explain how to check its a bad selector or not?

Comment: Reason could be that the DOM might have been updated (page refresh) for an element which you are trying to work on after inserting the records. Check the element before/after inserting the records.

Comment: Please, add a HTML snippet of your website and the locator you are using.

Comment: @Algiz I have updated question, Please have a look.